# Gmail app not sending Email with attachments

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, gmail

I have a lot of images I want to send from my phone to an email. I had in the past some error messages about emails being too big, so this time I sent in most emails 3 pics, which all queued in the `outbox`, and about 3 emails got through after a while. But now I have more than a day 20 emails in the `outbox` and it seems that nothing is happening. So my questions are:

1. Whats going wrong?
2. Is there anything I can do? (beside sending via BT to a computer, and email from there)

I have tried:

- Leaving the phone with open Wi-Fi connection all night
- Rebooting the phone (and leave another night with Wi-Fi)
- Checked at google's documentation and found out that they're limit is 25 MB per mail

Random info that might be relevant:

1. All mails are going to the same person with the same subject, and no body - gmail could be blocking them because a misuse is suspected.
2. I can surf the web as usual through the browser. No connection problems.
3. Each image is about 3MB, so each mail has a total of 9 MB.
4. There is exactly one email that has 4 images in it - not the first in the list.
5. First email in the list has only 2 images (both smaller that 2.9 MB)
6. I get notified about new emails I get.

Comment: I've had this problem before, very intermittent however so I don't have a solution. Uploads don't seem to work well...

Comment: Did you check with Logcat when sending? Might be some error messages/warnings could indicate what's going on. If unused to this, [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) could prove helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I think also for emails without attachments. The solution is to open the respective email. When I open it (by tapping on it in the `Outbox`), it gets sent within a few seconds (the caption goes from "Queued" to "Sending" to "Sent" or something like that within seconds).